# Анимация поля ввода при фокусе на мобильных

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, html5, autocomplete

Как создать анимацию поля ввода(поиска) для телефонов при его фокусе, при фокусе должен появляться бекграунд под полем поиска и ниже должен бить список аutocomplete вероятных запросов? Пример анимации вы можете посмотреть на сайте (только на мобильнике) - agoda.com

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так там инпута нет, просто стилизация контенера, по клику на которые выезжает другой и фокусируется на инпуте в нем.

Answer (score 0):

```css
input {
  transition: all.5s;
}

input:focus {
  background: red;
  transition: all.5s;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" autocomplete="on">
```